# "args" and "kwargs" which one use where amoung touple, list and dictonary?

Tags: python

I should need to be clear about the two method where i can use.

what should be the right ans:

```
is both are touple

args is tuple and kwargs is dictonary 

args is dictonary and kwargs is tuple

args is list and kwargs is tuple

both are list
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, lets try it out assuming you talk about [function arguments and keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
>>> def foo(*args, **kwargs):
...   print(type(args))
...   print(type(kwargs))
... 
>>> foo(1,2,x=3,y=4)
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'dict'>
```

Therefore `args` is a `tuple` and `kwargs` is a `dict`.

Comment: This, of course, assumes common naming conventions and that the OP is actually talking about function arguments. I can easily make a `list` called `kwargs` :)

Comment: Of course you are right. I updated my answer, just in case :D